# Django model designing

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am failry new to django , need help with django model.

I need to store below type of record in my `sqlite` database in django.
How can I design a model that can store this data .

I can use `SmallIntegerField` to store Room_no and `CharField` to store Student_name.

But I am not sure how to store the `Sports` array. I want to store it in such way that in case if I have to list out all the students for any sport , querying the database should be efficient.

```
  {
    "Room_no": 2,
    "Student_name": "XYZ",
    "Sports": [
      "Football",
      "Tennis",
      "Cricket"
    ]  
  }
```

One way I could think of is :

```
class Sports(models.Model):
        sports = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Student(models.Model):
        Student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        Room_no = models.IntegerField()
        sports = models.ManyToManyField(Sports)
```

Django version: 1.8.3

Comment: I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based because this question is only superficially about Django -- it is primarily about how to lay out a database schema. There are many good answers on this point, and trade-offs between query speed ("querying the database should be efficient") and [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it along with some other code style changes that are standard for python and Django.

```
# Your models name should be singular rather than plural.
class Sport(models.Model):
        # Use name here rather than sports since it's more descriptive.
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Student(models.Model):
        # You're in the student model, it can be assumed that the name is the student's name.
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        # The fields should be lower case.
        room_no = models.IntegerField()
        sports = models.ManyToManyField(Sport)
```